# Creating a table from summarized data using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to create a summary table from summarized data using dplyr.

```r
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% group_by(cyl, gear) %>% summarise(avg_wt = mean(wt))
```

Here's the output:

```
# A tibble: 8 x 3
# Groups:   cyl [3]
    cyl  gear avg_wt
  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1     4     3   2.46
2     4     4   2.38
3     4     5   1.83
4     6     3   3.34
5     6     4   3.09
6     6     5   2.77
7     8     3   4.10
8     8     5   3.37
```

How can I generate this output?

columns are cyl and rows are gear:

```
    4       6       8
3   2.46    3.34    4.10
4   2.38    3.09    NA
5   1.83    2.77    3.37
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tibble)

mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl, gear) %>%
  summarise(avg_wt = mean(wt)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    id_cols     = "gear",
    names_from  = "cyl",
    values_from = "avg_wt"
  ) %>% 
  column_to_rownames("gear")
#>          4       6        8
#> 3 2.465000 3.33750 4.104083
#> 4 2.378125 3.09375       NA
#> 5 1.826500 2.77000 3.370000
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
mytable <- mtcars %>% group_by(cyl, gear) %>% summarise(avg_wt = mean(wt))

tidyr::spread(mytable, cyl, avg_wt)
```

You should get the following:

```
   gear   `4`   `6`   `8`
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     3  2.46  3.34  4.10
2     4  2.38  3.09 NA   
3     5  1.83  2.77  3.37
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I get this as output: ```# A tibble: 8 x 4
  avg_wt   `4`   `6`   `8`
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1   1.83     5    NA    NA
2   2.38     4    NA    NA
3   2.46     3    NA    NA
4   2.77    NA     5    NA
5   3.09    NA     4    NA
6   3.34    NA     3    NA
7   3.37    NA    NA     5
8   4.10    NA    NA     3```

Comment: I edited my code. There was an error in the spread function. You can try now.

Comment: Also you can convert to dataframe with ```as.data.frame()``` and pipe ```tibble::column_to_rownames("gear")```